# Format custom date using dayjs

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I'm working on migrating from `momentjs` to `dayjs`

How to format a custom date format into a standard one using `dayjs`. For e.g., I'm trying to format a date in `YYYY-MM-DD+h:mm` format to `YYYY-MM-DD`. dayjs gives me an `NaN`

Works perfectly fine with `moment` this way -

`moment(effectiveDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD+h:mm').format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

There are lots of such occurrences in my codebase, so I'm trying not to rely on string manipulation to achieve this.

I've been using this [repl](https://repl.it/repls/AncientSlipperyApache) to try things out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dayjs` version `1.8.20` and extend [CustomParseFormat](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/custom-parse-format) package.

In html file:

```
...
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.20/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.20/plugin/customParseFormat.js"></script>
...
```

The first let's extent dayjs object:

```
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_customParseFormat);
```

Now, you can play with your format:

```
const dateString  = dayjs("2019-06-06+4:56", "YYYY-MM-DD+h:mm").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log("Date: ", dateString);
```

Output: `Date:  2019-06-06`

Comment: Thanks buddy, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way, **hope this will help you**

```
let customFormat = dayjs('2019-06-06+4:56'.replace('+','T')+':00').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
console.log('Custom format conversion1 - ', customFormat )
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure this out, but I'm trying to figure out a way without any string manipulations. I have quite a few different date formats and wouldnt want to rely on string manipulations everywhere. If nothing works out, this would have to be my last resort though.

Comment: yes sure, but i don't think so that there is any option rather then using string manipulations, i have cross check with the document dayjs :- http://zetcode.com/javascript/dayjs/